# #include dependencies management with autotools

Tags: autotools, automake, include-path

I code some C++ software and manage the whole project with the GNU autotools.

I have some part of the C++ code which is really verbose so I have made a script "generator.rb" which generate it automatically in a file "generated.cpp".

I have a build target "generated.cpp" that construct "generated.cpp" from "object_list.txt"

Up to this point everything works correctly.

Now I want to #include this "generated.cpp" file in another one "handwritten.cpp".

Since automake is said to automaticaly compute the dependencies on included files, I expect it to :

- rebuild "generated.cpp" when building "handwritten.o", if it does not exist or is not up-to-date
- trigger a new "handwritten.o" build each time object_list.txt has changed

So how can I do that ?

Remark : My source tree is like that :

```
./
\_src/
|  \_handwritten.cpp
|_design/
|  \_object_list.txt
\_tools/
   \_generator.rb
```

Remark : My build tree is like that :

```
build/
 \_gcc_debug/
    |_src/
    |  \_handwritten.o
    \_design/
       \_generated.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since automake is said to automaticaly compute the dependencies on included files

Because Automake-generated Makefiles generate dependencies as a side effect of compilation, a file that is created as part of the build needs special treatment.  You have to tell Automake to build such a file before it tries any of the normal compilations.  This is done using [BUILT_SOURCES](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html), like:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = generated.cpp
```

... followed by writing the rules you need to create `generated.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. Just a precision that may be useful for other : this can work only when doing "make" or "make check", not when doing "make handwritten.o" (see the BUILT_SOURCES link above). But for now it is quite sufficient for me.